# How can I make my code more readable with multiple css selectors

Tags: python, selenium

I am looking for a way to shorten my code.

I am gathering captcha values from https://www.ultimateqa.com/complicated-page/ and submitting them for 3 captcha boxes.

Can I shorten my code using a function?
Or should I use different css selectors?

```
for i in range(1):
    cap0 = '#et_pb_contact_form_0 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
    captext1= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap0).get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext1)
    captext2= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap0).get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext2)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap0).send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

```
for i in range(1):
    cap1 = '#et_pb_contact_form_1 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
    captext1= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap1).get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext1)
    captext2= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap1).get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext2)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap1).send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

```
for i in range(1):
    cap2 = '#et_pb_contact_form_2 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
    captext1= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap2).get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext1)
    captext2= driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap2).get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext2)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap2).send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the name attribute with the loop index as parameter

```
for i in range(3):
    cap = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f'[name="et_pb_contact_captcha_{i}"]')
    captext = cap.get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext)
    captext = cap.get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext)
    cap.send_keys(capnumb + capnumb2)
```

Or locate all the captcha by partial name and iterate over the list

```
captchas = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[name^="et_pb_contact_captcha_"]')

for cap in captchas:
    captext = cap.get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext)
    captext = cap.get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext)
    cap.send_keys(capnumb + capnumb2)
```

No need to relocate the captcha field every time, locate it once and use it.

Comment: That is another great solution. I am learning alot, thanks :p

Answer (score 2):

You can use selector that matches all 3 cases (just separate CSS selectors with comma) and handle them in a loop:

```
cap_css = '#et_pb_contact_form_0 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input, #et_pb_contact_form_1 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input, #et_pb_contact_form_2 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
cap_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(cap_css)
for cap in cap_list:
    captext1= cap.get_attribute("data-first_digit")
    capnumb1 = int(captext1)
    captext2= cap.get_attribute("data-second_digit")
    capnumb2 = int(captext2)
    cap.send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

P.S. `for i in range(1)` loop should be removed as it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Good to know! that makes things alot easier, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Few pythonic/programmatic notes:

- A for loop with range(1) is iterating once (on the 0th element); thus, not very useful as regular code iterates once anyways.
- Anytime you see similar code being written down, you can generally abstract the logic into reusable code.

I'm personally unfamiliar with selenium and not that great with CSS, but here's a go at the python:

```
def get_digit(cap,attr):
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap).get_attribute(attr)
    return (element, int(element))

caps = ['#et_pb_contact_form_0', '#et_pb_contact_form_1', '#et_pb_contact_form_2']
cap_end = ' > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
for cap in caps:
    tmp_cap = cap + cap_end
    captext1, capnumb1 = get_digit(tmp_cap, "data-first_digit")
    captext2, capnumb2 = get_digit(tmp_cap, "data-second_digit")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(tmp_cap).send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

Let me know in a comment if this works for you!

Using my function with JaSON's combined CSS selectors logic:

```
def get_digit(cap,attr):
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cap).get_attribute(attr)
    return (element, int(element))

cap_css = '#et_pb_contact_form_0 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input, #et_pb_contact_form_1 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input, #et_pb_contact_form_2 > div.et_pb_contact > form > div > div > p > input'
cap_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(cap_css)
for cap in cap_list:
    captext1, capnumb1 = get_digit(cap, "data-first_digit")
    captext2, capnumb2 = get_digit(cap, "data-second_digit")
    cap.send_keys(capnumb1 + capnumb2)
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! I have no knowledge of Selenium haha... Also, I updated my answer to include a merge of JaSON's answer and mine own. That should also work assuming the combined selector is valid.